# graceful restart of httpd, configured by Chef

Tags: apache, chef-infra

I configured `httpd` with Chef via community httpd recipe.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd

```
httpd_service "default" do
    action [:create, :start]
end
```

After executing above code,  `sudo service httpd-default graceful` gives the following error:

```
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for web01
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

`sudo service httpd-default status` says httpd is running.

How can I gracefully restart httpd manually?
My target server is CentOS 6.6.

Comment: is your fqdn set?  run `hostname -f` and see what you get.

Comment: `hostname -f` outputs `hostname: Unknown host` but I think that's another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apachectl -f /etc/httpd-default/conf/httpd.conf -k graceful
```

this command resolved my problem.